# Using Hexdump In Bash Script does not correctly handle Unicode Characters

Tags: bash, unicode, hexdump

Using Hexdump in Bash script to convert Unicode values does not work as expected.

I can enter the following, directly in the terminal:

```
echo -e "\u2022" | hexdump -C
```

This yields the following expected result:

> 00000000  e2 80 a2 0a

However when I attempt to use the **exact** command in a bash script I get the following:

> 00000000  5c 75 32 30 32 32 0a                              |\u2022.|

Any ideas what could be the cause of the differing outputs? Seems that an additional 3 bytes are added to the output and the U value doesn't appear to be converted.

Comment: Expansion of unicode `\u` sequences is nonstandard (actually, even just `echo -e` is nonstandard), and will work differently in different shells, different versions of the same shell, the same shell with different modes/parameters set, etc. You could probably track down the difference between your interactive shell environment and the script environment, but IMO it's not worth it. It'd be better to find a more robust way to do the translation.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for your feedback. Are you aware of a more robust way to undertake conversions of this nature? I'd prefer not to have to write a low-level character conversion utility, if at all possible.

Comment: Try to use `printf "\u2022" | hexdump -C` which should give same result in both cases.

Comment: @Philippe Actually using printf doesn't help. The output is still different when you execute hexdump directly in the terminal and from within the context of a bash script.

Comment: That is odd, what are the shells (and version) in both cases ?

Comment: Testing this in OSX Terminal using Bash version 5.2. and I run the script in the same terminal instance.

Comment: What's your shebang? `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @Fravadona /bin/bash

Comment: try with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: `/bin/bash --version` on OSX gives `GNU bash, version 3.2.57` which is a very old version.

Comment: I did previously. However I updated my bash version during the course of debugging this problem and thus running: echo $BASH_VERSION, on my system, now returns:5.2.15(1)-release

Comment: Ok, so I think I've narrowed it down to how quote characters are handled by hexdump. If I enter: echo -e \u2022 | hexdump I get:0000000 75 32 30 32 32 0a in both the terminal AND the script. However the value I need is: 00000000 e2 80 a2 0a which is the valid hex value that can be used to print the associated Unicode character to the screen.

Comment: @Fravadona and GordonDavisson thank you very much indeed for your input Sirs. As you both correctly deduced it was a bash environment issue. Notwithstanding the fact that I'd update my bash version and set the new version as the default. The OLD environment was still being picked up by scripts. Once I ran with :#!/usr/bin/env bash as suggested by Fravadona the script began to function as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same `printf` command works in the Terminal but not in the script then it means that they're not using the same `bash` interpreter. Try setting the shebang of the script to:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

---

That said, here would be a workaround for printing UTF-8 codepoints in the range `U+0800`-`U+FFFF` (3-bytes) with a **standard** shell that supports 32-bit arithmetic:

```bash
# U+2022
u=0x2022

f=$(printf '\\x%x' \
    "$(( (u & 0xF000 | 0xE0000) >> 12 ))" \
    "$(( (u & 0xFC0  | 0x2000 ) >>  6 ))" \
    "$(( (u & 0x3F   | 0x80   )       ))"
)

printf "$f\\n"
```

```
•
```

Comment: Cheers for your assistance @Fravadona your answer provides a good workaround.